# What are the chips to build usb device?

Tags: microcontroller, usb, microchip, usb-device

I want to make some device, that should just do one thing - send few values - x,y and z via usb, so at pc end, for example there will be a driver for that device, which some program can access and call some `getX()` function.

This device is intended to be cheap and also tiny (not bigger than 16 cm^2, like 4*4 cm). Because of that reasons I can't use Arduion, Raspberry PI or something like that.

Is there chips that are made for just pass some physical data (current, voltage value) through usb? How expensive are they?

---

For example, I found chip CH340G. I am not sure is that what can help me, is that what I am looking for, but at least it seems to be. It pretty cheap - about 0.8 usd, it is acceptable for me, but of course, if there is something cheaper it will be nice.

Comment: Note that buying recommendation is off topic here, but I strongly recommend reading the articles [The Amazing $1 Microcontroller](https://jaycarlson.net/microcontrollers/) and [So you want to build an embedded Linux system?](https://jaycarlson.net/embedded-linux/) by Jay Carlson. The author has reviewed more than 20 models.

Comment: @比尔盖子 okay, I update my question. I rather interested on is there chips for that purposes at all

Comment: Could you clarify what size you mean?  "tiny" isn't as helpful as X by Y mm.

Comment: @jonathanjo, clarified

Comment: yes. it's suitable. That answers the question.

Comment: @比尔盖子 it seems like that models are too cool for my goal. There are RAM, and other stuff, that, I think I do not need.

Comment: @MarcusMüller You are about CH340G?

Comment: @jsotola, well, probably, not acceptable in my case, because I want to sell device in big amounts. So, finding thousands keyboards for every thousand devices is bad idea

Comment: @Stdugnd4ikbd this is why providing incomplete information wastes everybody's time

Answer (score 2):

For a general-purpose solution, you might care to reconsider anything made from an ATMega32u4  Many boards are cheaply available which are smaller than your requirement: here are a couple.

[image]

Comment: it is about 7 usd, it is too expensive

Comment: @Stdugnd4ikbd ok, so you **are** just looking for a price efficient component – voting to close

Comment: Kindly put your requirements in your question.  "cheap" is a very relative term.  Some are muhc lower than that, it depends where you buy them.

Comment: @jonathanjo actually I mentioned specific price, that acceptable for me